# redirect with variable

Tags: codeigniter, redirect

I'm sorry if I ask a silly question.

if in view `$this->load->view('some_view', $data);`, can I use it on redirect like this `redirect('some_controller', $data)`?

once again, sorry if I asking a silly question, thank you

Comment: :Can you please elaborate your question.

Comment: You can't redirect with $data like that, however you can use $this->session->set_flashdata('name', 'your data') right before the redirect and use the flashdata on the redirected to controller.

Comment: @WesleyMurch great minds and all that ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately no, you cannot do this that way - but you could perhaps use session "[flashdata](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html)".

```
$this->session->set_flashdata('my_data', $data);
redirect('some_controller');
```

Then in "some_controller":

```
$flash_data = $this->session->flashdata('my_data');
if ($flash_data)
{
    $this->load->vars($flash_data);
}
```

There could be issues with large amounts of data, so I would suggest finding another approach if possible.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>
    window.location.href='http://localhost/some_controller/$data';
    </SCRIPT>";
```

Comment: Please add some explenation to your answer.